# Launch Fleet IDE with CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface, zsh, jetbrains-fleet

I have installed Fleet IDE on MacOS and would like to have it be opened using my terminal as well. Currently, it says that `fleet` is not a recognized command and I need to add the script to launch fleet in the $PATH variable. How can I do that? Also, would appreciate some help on understanding how this works (like how I can do `code .` and have VSCode be opened up in the current folder).

Comment: Find out the full path to the executable that is launched and then run that from the CLI. Optionally add the directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/launch-from-cli.html) says you should use Toolbox App to configure Fleet command line launcher:

**Generate scripts﻿**

1. In the Toolbox app, click **Toolbox App menu**, then select **Settings**.
   [image]
2. Under **Tools**, enable **Generate shell scripts**.
3. In **Shell scripts location**, specify a folder that is accessible through the PATH variable.

**Configure command name﻿**

1. In the Toolbox app, click **Tool** actions near **Fleet**, then select **Settings**.
   [image]
2. Under **Shell script name**, specify the name for the command that launches JetBrains Fleet.